# Excel - special paste options?

Tags: excel, vba, paste

I need some help. Let's say that I would like to copy a long...long.. row in Excel:

`2.337662338    2.368421053 2.479452055 2.283950617 2.72    2.625`

What should I do to copy this row and paste it in such a form:

`2.337662338    2.368421053 2.479452055`
`2.283950617    2.72    2.625` etc...

Thank you very much for your willingness to help.
Cheers.
Luke

Comment: Is your data in the long row really just integers in ascending order? In that case you can use some simple formulas to generate the data and then copy&paste (values only) the result.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change the order.. :(

Comment: You do not have to. My question is if your data is like the sample you provided in your question (integers in ascending order). In that case your problem can easily be solved.

Comment: No it is not in ascending order. Sample from my data: 

`2.337662338 2.368421053 2.479452055 2.283950617 2.72 2.625 2.649350649 2.506024096 2.551282051 2.414634146 2.5 2.43902439 2.846153846`

Comment: Ok, you may want to copy that to your question. You will probably Need some vba (Visual Basic) script to achieve the result you want. To increase the chance of an answer for that, you may want to include the vba tag in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your data in `A1:J1` you can enter the following formula in `A2`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$J$1,1,(ROW(1:1)-1)*4+COLUMN(A:A)),"")
```

And drag it down to `D4`.

Result:

[image]

Change `*4` if you need more columns.